# Multiple entity manager for FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

To use different Entity Manager / Connection based on URL in Symfony if fairly easy. With the following routing configuration

```php
connection:
    pattern:  /a/{connection}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:User:index }
```

and from the following Cookbook;

[How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

My controller would look something like this;

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($connection)
    {

        $products = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product', $connection)
            ->findAll()
        ;
        ..................
```

and I'll be able to fetch product information from different em/connection/database.

Now, if I add something like this to my routing;

```php
login:
    pattern:  /a/{connection}/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }
```

How can I easily make the *login* to use connection as defined in the *connection* variable?

This setup assume each database has their own user login information (the fos_user table).

**Edit: Updated routing information**

**Edit2:**

I'm still new with PHP/Symfony/Doctrine though, so please forgive me if I'm completely wrong here. I tried to manually set the connection at *FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager*. The following is the constructor of the class

```php
//
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
//

public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer, CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer, ObjectManager $om, $class)
{
    parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer);

    $this->objectManager = $om;
    $this->repository = $om->getRepository($class);

    $metadata = $om->getClassMetadata($class);
    $this->class = $metadata->getName();
}
```

In a controller, we can use the following method to change the em to 'testing'

```php
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('testing');
$repository = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository($class, 'testing')
```

For that I changed the code to the following to use EntityManager instead of ObjectManager.

```php
//
//use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
//

public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer, CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer, EntityManager $om, $class)
{
    parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer);

    $this->objectManager = $om;
    $this->repository = $om->getRepository($class);

    $metadata = $om->getClassMetadata($class);
    $this->class = $metadata->getName();
}
```

My app works fine with no error.

From the way it works with the controller, I tried changing the connection by adding a parameter to this line then, but it's still using the default connection.

```php
$this->repository = $om->getRepository($class, 'testing');
```

What else could I be missing here?

Comment: I don't think the FOSUserBundle is designed to do that. You could extend the functionality, either by contributing to the project itself or creating a fork. Or you could write your own UserBundle with support for different connections.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes: I completely agree with you. I'm not yet able to find a solution/workaround to his problem of mine, but when I do, I sure will share it here, if not by a pull request at github :)

Comment: Have you injected the proper object manager into the UserManager class constructor (the testing one)?

Comment: fos_user.entity_manager:
        alias: doctrine.orm.porting_entity_manager   This should work?

Answer (score 12):

As you can see, FOSUserBundle can have only one EntityManager. You can see it from the settings **orm.xml**

```
<service id="fos_user.entity_manager" factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getManager" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" public="false">
    <argument>%fos_user.model_manager_name%</argument>
</service>
```

Parameter %fos_user.model_manager_name% specified in settings as model_manager_name

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:            ~ # Required
    user_class:           ~ # Required
    firewall_name:        ~ # Required
    model_manager_name:   ~
```

So into the constructor comes the instance of EntityManager, which does not accept the second parameter in the getRepository. Therefore, the standard FOSUserBundle can only work with one database.

---

But this is not the end of story, it's Symfony :)
We can write out UserManager, that can use different db connections. In the setting see that fos_user.user_manager is a fos_user.user_manager.default. We find it in orm.xml

```
<service id="fos_user.user_manager.default" class="FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="security.encoder_factory" />
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer" />
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer" />
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.entity_manager" />
    <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
</service>
```

We can override this class to add an additional parameter that will determine what kind of connection you want to use. Further by ManagerFactory you can get the desired ObjectManager. I wrote simple example for the two databeses (if you need more databases you can write your factory for this service)

define your services in services.yml

```
services:
    acme.user_manager.conn1:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\UserManager
        public: true
        arguments:
            - @security.encoder_factory
            - @fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer
            - @fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer
            - @doctrine
            - 'conn1_manager'
            - %fos_user.model.user.class%

    acme.user_manager.conn2:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\UserManager
        public: true
        arguments:
            - @security.encoder_factory
            - @fos_user.util.username_canonicalizer
            - @fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer
            - @doctrine
            - 'conn2_manager'
            - %fos_user.model.user.class%
```

Your manager

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory
 * @param CanonicalizerInterface  $usernameCanonicalizer
 * @param CanonicalizerInterface  $emailCanonicalizer
 * @param RegistryInterface       $doctrine
 * @param string                  $connName
 * @param string                  $class
 */
public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer,
                            CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer, RegistryInterface $doctrine, $connName, $class)
{
    $om = $doctrine->getEntityManager($connName);
    parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer, $om, $class);
}

/**
 * Just for test
 * @return EntityManager
 */
public function getOM()
{
    return $this->objectManager;
}
```

and simple test

```
/**
 * phpunit -c app/ src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/FOSUser/FOSUserMultiConnection.php
 */
class FOSUserMultiConnection extends WebTestCase
{
    public function test1()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        /** @var $user_manager_conn1 UserManager */
        $user_manager_conn1 = $client->getContainer()->get('acme.user_manager.conn1');

        /** @var $user_manager_conn2 UserManager */
        $user_manager_conn2 = $client->getContainer()->get('acme.user_manager.conn2');

        /** @var $om1 EntityManager */
        $om1 = $user_manager_conn1->getOM();
        /** @var $om2 EntityManager */
        $om2 = $user_manager_conn2->getOM();

        $this->assertNotEquals($om1->getConnection()->getDatabase(), $om2->getConnection()->getDatabase());
    }
}
```

I'm sorry that the answer was so big. If something is not clear to the end, I put the code on [github](https://github.com/i4got10/symfony-standard/tree/fos_multi)

Answer (score 1):

FosUserBundle is not able to have more than one entity manager.

The easiest way I found to use 2 databases, is to override the 'checkLoginAction' of the SecurityController.

```
<?php
//in myuserBunle/Controller/SecurityController.php

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{

    /**
    * check the user information 
    */

    public function checkLoginAction(Request $request){
            $username = \trim($request->request->get("_username"));
            $user    =   $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername($username);
        $userDB2 =   .....


            $password = \trim($request->request->get('_password'));


            if ($user) {
              // Get the encoder  for the users password
              $encoder      =  $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
              $encoded_pass =  $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());

              if (($user->getPassword() == $encoded_pass) || $this->checkSecondEM()) {
                $this->logUser($request, $user);
                return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate($this->container->get('session')->get('route'), $request->query->all() ));
              } else {
                // Password bad
                  return parent::loginAction($request);   
              }
            } else {
              // Username bad
                return parent::loginAction($request);   
            }
        }

}
```