# Change service parameter value dynamically for FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle

I asked about [using multiple entity manager for FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475180/multiple-entity-manager-for-fosuserbundle) before, and it turns out that FOSUserBundle has (partially) supported that. All I need to do is to specify the connection / manager I want to use in the `model_manager_name` parameter, as explained [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md)

```
fos_user:
# ........
    model_manager_name: account1
```

*Sample app/config/config.yml*

With this FOSUserBundle will use `account1` connection, and use user information in that connection's database.

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
    account2:
        dbname:           account2
        user:             account2
        password:         password2
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     localhost
        port:     ~
        charset:  UTF8
    account1:
        dbname:           account1
        user:             account1
        password:         password1
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     localhost
        port:     ~
        charset:  UTF8
    default:
        dbname:           account
        user:             account
        password:         password
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     localhost
        port:     ~
        charset:  UTF8
```

My app require that when a user goes to (for example) http://myapp.com/a/account1, the app will use `account1` connection, and going to http://myapp.com/a/account2 will use `account2`'s connection. For my application's logic, this is easily done from my controllers as I could use something like the following;

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('account2');
$repository = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository($class, 'account2')
```

For the login part though, it's not that easy. FOSUserBundle runs as a service container, and I don't know where/how to dynamically change the `model_manager_name`'s value. I do know though that in `FOS\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\FOSUserExtension` I can manually change its value the following way;

```
class FOSUserExtension extends Extension
{
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $processor = new Processor();
    $configuration = new Configuration();

    $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $config['model_manager_name'] = 'account2';
    // .................
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

The configuration is stored inside the container, in the `fos_user.model_manager_name` to be exact.

You can write a compiler pass. This will be executed just before freezing the container, it is the last place where you can change the container and it is the place to change the container based on other services.

Your compiler pass will look like this:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ChangeModelManagerPass.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class ChangeModelManagerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $request = $container->get('request');
        $uri = $request->getUri();

        // check if the uri matches some pattern which will cause a change in the
        // `model_manager_name` setting
        if (...) {
            // ... do some stuff to get the correct model manager name

            // set the setting
            $container->setParameter('fos_user.model_manager_name', ...);
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about compiler passes in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) or in [this great blog post](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/02/15/symfony2-service-container-compiler-passes/) by Richard Miller.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to compiler pass! I can't access the 'request' service though, as I got this error;

`RuntimeException: You have requested a synthetic service ("request"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service.`

Any idea?

Comment: @MohdShakirZakaria you can't access the `request` service outside the `request` scope. I actually don't know how to solve this... :(

Comment: use `request_stack` service